# How to resolve Null pointer exception while invoke the driver instance fron one class to another class using Dependency injection with cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber

I am using Dependency injection technique to invoke the driver in my step definition class,
In the first class, I have initialized the chrome driver and set it to the DI class.
But while running the code, it's not sharing to my next step Definition Class.

Created a driver in the DIClass and then initiated the chrome driver in the login class.
and then set the chrome driver object to the DIClass driver but while reaching second step definition class, I am getting null pointer error on hamburger method.

```
DIClass:

public class DIClass {

    public WebDriver driver;
    

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {

        this.driver = driver;
    }

StepDefinition class:

public class LoginPage extends DIClass{

    DIClass base;

    public LoginPage(DIClass testContextUI) {

        this.base = testContextUI;
    }



    @Given("I open a {string} browser")
    public void i_open_a_browser(String browser) {
//        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/vinoth/eclipse-workspace/yocoBoardI/chromedriver");
//        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
//        base.signIn = PageFactory.initElements(base.driver, SignIn.class);

    }


    @Given("I navigate to url {string}")
    public void i_navigate_to_url(String url) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/vinoth/eclipse-workspace/yocoBoardI/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        base.setDriver(driver);
        base.signIn = PageFactory.initElements(base.driver, SignIn.class);
        base.driver.get(url);


    }


    @When("user login into application with {string} and {string}")
    public void user_login_into_application_with_and(String string, String string2) {

        base.signIn.normalSignIn(string, string2);

    }


    @Then("I navigated to Hours page")
    public void i_navigated_to_Hours_page() throws InterruptedException {
        base.hoursPage = PageFactory.initElements(base.driver, HoursPage.class);
        base.hoursPage.validateHOursPage();

//        base.pages = PageFactory.initElements(base.driver, LeftSideBar.class);
//        base.pages.clockInOut();

       // base.driver.quit();
    }

}

2nd Class:

public class ProfileSettings {
  //  WebDriver driver;
    DIClass base;
    LoginPage loginPage;
    public ProfileSettings(DIClass testContextUI) {

        this.base = testContextUI;

    }

    @Given("User should see the hamburger icon")
    public void user_should_see_the_hamburger_icon() {
      //  base.setDriver(driver);
        base.profileSettings = PageFactory.initElements(base.driver, ProfileSettingsPage.class);
        base.profileSettings.hamburgerIcon();  - here i am getting the error .

    }

    @When("I clicks the profile settings label")
    public void i_clicks_the_profile_settings_label() {

        base.profileSettings.openFooterPopup();
    }

    @Then("landed to the respective page.")
    public void landed_to_the_respective_page() {

        base.profileSettings.validateProfileSettingsPage();
    }

    @When("I upload Invalid {string} formats")
    public void i_upload_Invalid_formats(String string) {
        //StringSelection is a class that can be used for copy and paste operations.
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(string);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
        base.profileSettings.fileUpload("Mac");
    }

    @Then("Should see the respective voice message")
    public void should_see_the_respective_voice_message() {

            base.profileSettings.fileUploadValidation();
    }
```

Comment: `LoginPage` should not extend `DIClass`. That might throws things off.

Comment: I did that. It's not working.

Comment: I have initiated chromeDriver in login page and then set that driver to the DIclass driver. 
So how it will works in profileSettings class?

Comment: Both pages should have the same instance of the DIClass injected. You can check this in the debugger.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more with example, It could be helpful to solve my issue.

Comment: Nah. This is a skill you have to learn. Try making your problem smaller. Remove all but two steps, remove the webdriver. Remove everything you don't need. Then try and pass a string between two steps and follow along with the debugger. Write down the object ids if you have to.

Comment: Thanks. I did it and I got the solution.

Comment: Cool! Congrats.

Answer (score 0):

```
import depenencyInjection.DIClass;
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
public class DriverClass extends DIClass {
    DIClass base;
    public DriverClass(DIClass testContextUI) {
        this.base = testContextUI;
    }
    @Before
    public void testStep()
    {
        if(base.getDriver() ==null) {
            System.out.println("Test Environment Setup");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Filepath");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            base.driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            base.driver.navigate().to("https:********");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Created the class where i have initialized the chrome driver with Dependecy injection object.
And If you use @Before, it will open the browser for each scenario, So avoid that, we should check  whether the driver has value or not. If there is no value, then only we should initiate the browser.